# Load partitioned (spark) parquet to a bigquery table

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, parquet

I have data written out from spark, to parquet files in gcs, partitioned on a date column. The data in gcs look like this:

```
gs://mybucket/dataset/fileDate=2019-06-17/000.parquet
gs://mybucket/dataset/fileDate=2019-06-17/001.parquet
```

**I'd like to load this to bigquery, such that the column `fileDate` in the resulting (partitioned) table is populated from the path. How can I do this?**

What I've tried so far, is to create the table and load the data to it with

```
bq --location=US load --source_format=PARQUET 'workspace:marcin_test.dataset_table' 'gs://mybucket/dataset/fileDate=2019-06-17/*'
```

This works in so far as data are loaded, but fileDate is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that they are hive partitioned since they look like this but correct me if I am wrong. Try this:- `bq load --source_format=PARQUET --autodetect --hive_partitioning_mode=AUTO --hive_partitioning_source_uri_prefix=gs://mybucket/dataset/ project-id:dataset_name.table_name gs://mybucket/dataset/fileDate=2019-06-17/*.parquet`

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-loads-gcs 
It should work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please format the code in your answers accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for this. Looks like the feature is very new.

Comment: From what I can see here the the partitions are added into the final table but no actual partitioning happens on the created table

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in feature to accomplish this when loading data. Possible workarounds would be:

1. Load the data to a staging table and use an extra step to pass the data to the definitive table, adding the column containing the path.
2. Do some ETL process (for example with Dataprep or Dataflow) instead of loading your data using the bq tool.